# iOS - SKNavigationSettings zoom level configuration

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

I have an issue with auto zoom during navigation. I followed the official docs but auto zoom doesn't work. Here my test code

```
SKSpeedInterval speed1;
speed1.minimumSpeed = 1;
speed1.maximumSpeed = 45;

SKSpeedInterval speed2;
speed2.minimumSpeed = 46;
speed2.maximumSpeed = 300;

SKZoomLevelConfiguration *level1 = [[SKZoomLevelConfiguration alloc] init];
SKZoomLevelConfiguration *level2 = [[SKZoomLevelConfiguration alloc] init];

level1.speedInterval = speed1;
level2.speedInterval = speed2;

level1.zoomLevel = kMaximumZoomLimit;
level2.zoomLevel = kMaximumZoomLimit-2;

SKNavigationSettings* navSettings = [SKNavigationSettings navigationSettings];
navSettings.navigationType = SKNavigationTypeReal;
navSettings.zoomLevelConfigurations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:level1, level2, nil];

[level1 release];
[level2 release];

[[SKRoutingService sharedInstance] startNavigationWithSettings:navSettings];
```

Have you any idea about what is going wrong?

Comment: This issue is under investigation on the C++ level

Comment: Hi any news about this issue?

Comment: If you're trying to use it in 3D it won't work - is this the scenario that you're testing?

Comment: Yes, but I've found a workaround. I change region's zoom level based on speed. It's not the best solution but it works